# how to replace a class specific for IE using Deferred binding in GWT

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I'm trying to implement gwt deferred binding because IE doesn't render an animation properly.
I have a Class for IE (CardExp) an one for Chrome, firefox, etc... (Card) both extends a common parent (CardGeneral)

in my gwt.xml i have this:

```
<replace-with class="myapp.client.CardAll">
    <when-type-is class="myapp.client.Card"/>
  </replace-with>

  <!-- IE  -->
  <replace-with class="myapp.client.CardExp">
    <when-type-is class="myapp.client.Card"/>
  <any>
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie8" />
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie9" />
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie10" />
    <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie11" />
  </any>
  </replace-with>
```

And in my EntryPoint i have

```
final Card card = GWT.create(Card.class);
RootPanel.get().add(card);
```

In IE my app loads CardAll insted of CardExp. What am i missing to load CardExp in all versions of IE

Comment: I believe that you should be able to use wild cards in the `value` field. So `<when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie*" />`

Comment: @Jonathan it would be awesome but not possible `[ERROR] Invalid property value 'ie*'` thanks

Comment: I'll have to try out an entry point example when I have time. From the [2.5.1 UserAgent.gwt.xml](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.5.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml), you are missing ie9. Also of note is that ie6 support is being removed in 2.6, as seen [here](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/release/2.6/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml).

Comment: Also, there is an unofficial IRC channel where some people tend to hang out. ##gwt on irc.freenode.net. People tend to check it sporadically, so it is best to simply leave a question and wait for someone to reply. It has proven a great resource for me ;)

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet you have above looks right, but if you are using version 2.5.1, it looks like you are missing `ie9`.

The GWT docs on `gwt.xml` files has a sample which is very similar to yours. Look for the "Elements for Deferred Binding" section [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html).

Also take a look at the [2.5.1 tag of UserAgent.gwt.xml](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/2.5.1/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml).

Also of note is that `ie6` support is being removed in version 2.6.0, as seen [here](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/release/2.6/user/src/com/google/gwt/useragent/UserAgent.gwt.xml).

Comment: thanks, ie6 removed, ie9 added and also ie11. I'm testing in ie 11, but it seems that GWT doesn't support ie11, any workaround?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't been following the progress of IE 11 support. As I understand, integration with ie11 is still a work in progress. MS listed some [IE 11 compatibility issues on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx), the first of which is the user string. The GWT team made a (request for testers to report any issues with IE11)[http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2013/11/gwt-26-rc1-is-here.html]. That said, my best bet would be to browse the issue forums for possible answers.